# python recursion list passed is not getting updated

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to merge a list of lists recursively if there is something common between elements in order.
Example input: listt=[[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[4,5,6]]
Expected: output: [[4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3]]

Here is my function:

```
def merge(a, b):
    max_offset = len(b)  # can't overlap with greater size than len(b)
    for i in reversed(range(max_offset+1)):
        # checks for equivalence of decreasing sized slices
        if a[-i:] == b[:i]:
            return [a + b[i:]]
    return [a,b]


def recursive_func_test(listt,final_merged_list):
    something_changed=False
    for i, j in itertools.combinations(list(range(0,len(listt))), 2):    
        merged_list=merge(listt[i],listt[j])
        if len(merged_list)==1:
            final_merged_list.append(merged_list[0])
            something_changed=True
    if something_changed:
        for ele in listt:
            is_sub=False
            for ele_m in final_merged_list:
                if set(ele).issubset(set(ele_m)):
                    is_sub=True
            if not is_sub:
                final_merged_list.append(ele)    
        updated_merged_list=[]
        subset_list=[]
        for a, b in itertools.combinations(list(range(0,len(final_merged_list))), 2):
                if set(final_merged_list[a]).issubset(set(final_merged_list[b])):
                    subset_list.append(a)
                elif set(final_merged_list[b]).issubset(set(final_merged_list[a])):
                    subset_list.append(b)
        for i in range(len(final_merged_list)):
            if i not in subset_list:
                updated_merged_list.append(final_merged_list[i])
        final_merged_list=updated_merged_list
        final_merged_list=recursive_func_test(updated_merged_list,final_merged_list)
    else:
        return final_merged_list
```

Here is how I am trying to call the function:

```
listt=[[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[4,5,6]]
final_merged_list=[]
recursive_func_test(listt,final_merged_list)
print(final_merged_list)
```

The problem is my results is **[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]**  that is one recursion before the expected answer. Not sure where is the problem because when I add a print in the beginning of the function the value in final_merged_list is expected output. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer:

It is important to return the intermediate result to the outer call of recursion always. In the code after the line

```
final_merged_list=recursive_func_test(updated_merged_list,final_merged_list)
```

the result has to be returned so that when the recursion ends the innermost result (final merged list) is returned.

Here is the fixed code:

```
def recursive_func_test(listt,final_merged_list):
    something_changed=False
    for i, j in itertools.combinations(list(range(0,len(listt))), 2):    
        merged_list=merge(listt[i],listt[j])
        if len(merged_list)==1:
            final_merged_list.append(merged_list[0])
            something_changed=True
    if something_changed:
        for ele in listt:
            is_sub=False
            for ele_m in final_merged_list:
                if set(ele).issubset(set(ele_m)):
                    is_sub=True
            if not is_sub:
                final_merged_list.append(ele)    
        updated_merged_list=[]
        subset_list=[]
        for a, b in itertools.combinations(list(range(0,len(final_merged_list))), 2):
                if set(final_merged_list[a]).issubset(set(final_merged_list[b])):
                    subset_list.append(a)
                elif set(final_merged_list[b]).issubset(set(final_merged_list[a])):
                    subset_list.append(b)
        for i in range(len(final_merged_list)):
            if i not in subset_list:
                updated_merged_list.append(final_merged_list[i])
        final_merged_list=updated_merged_list
        final_merged_list=recursive_func_test(updated_merged_list,final_merged_list)
        return final_merged_list
    else:
        return final_merged_list
```

Also, Passing of an extra list can be avoided and code can be further simplified as shown below:

```
def recursive_func_test(listt):
    input_list=listt[:]
    something_changed=False
    final_merged_list=[]
    for i, j in itertools.combinations(list(range(0,len(listt))), 2): 
        merged_list=merge(listt[i],listt[j])
        if len(merged_list)==1:
            final_merged_list.append(merged_list[0])
            something_changed=True
    if something_changed:
        for ele in listt:
            is_sub=False
            for ele_m in final_merged_list:
                if set(ele).issubset(set(ele_m)):
                    is_sub=True
            if not is_sub:
                final_merged_list.append(ele)    
        
        subset_list=[]
        for a, b in itertools.combinations(list(range(0,len(final_merged_list))), 2):
                if set(final_merged_list[a]).issubset(set(final_merged_list[b])):
                    subset_list.append(a)
                elif set(final_merged_list[b]).issubset(set(final_merged_list[a])):
                    subset_list.append(b)
        
        for index in subset_list:
            final_merged_list.pop(index)
        listt=final_merged_list[:]
        result=recursive_func_test(listt)
        return result
    else:
        return listt
```

Answer (score 0):

In your merge function try doing :

```
a[-1] = b[i]
```

Comment: the problem is not with the merge function but hiw the list is handled in recursion. I am not able to figure that out.